# Is it possible to define an exception inside a function

Tags: ocaml

One way to implement "early returns" in OCaml is via exceptions:

```
exception Exit

let myfunc () = 
    try
      for i = 0 to .... do
        if .. then raise Exit
      done; false
    with Exit -> true
```

However, is there a way to declare this `Exit` exception in the body of the function, so its name is not visible to other functions in the module?

```
(* I would like to do this, but it gives a syntax error *)
let myfunc () = 
    exception Exit
    try
      for i = 0 to .... do
        if .. then raise Exit
      done; false
    with Exit -> true
```

Comment: Why do you think so? I think its more structured than writing a tail-recursive loop.

Comment: Relying on exceptions to drive business logic is usually icky to me although I don't know what you're using the exception for, maybe its legitimate like a fatal to the entire program kind of thing.

Comment: Exceptions are the closest we can get in Ocaml to `return` statements and I think using return statements to get out of a function early is justifiable. BTW, notice that we always catch the Exit exception in the same function that raised it so the control flow is relatively well behaved compared to unrestricted exceptions.

Comment: One of the reasons I like coding in OCaml is *exactly* to avoid stuff like code that has early returns.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian That's only your opinion. Some of us may be using data structures for which they only have iterators such as `fold` and `iter` with the usual types and meaning, and still want to implement `exists` (with the usual type and meaning) without iterating over the entire data structure before returning `true`. And that's completely what monads are for, but the point is that `Hashtbl` from the standard library, to take an example, contains `iter` and `fold` and does not contain `monadic_fold`.

Comment: There's a predefined `Exit` exception for this purpose. Works well in practice without having to make it private.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people from the future like me, we can use local exceptions which was introduced in OCaml 4.04:

```ml
let myfunc () = 
  let exception Exit in
  try
    for i = 0 to 3 do
      if true then raise Exit
    done; false
  with Exit -> true
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, what you want is possible by using a local module:

```
let myfunc () = 
  let module M = struct exception Exit end in
  try
    for i = 0 to 3 do
      if true then raise M.Exit
    done; false
  with M.Exit -> true
```

That style is not particularly pleasant to read, though, so I wouldn't recommend it. It is enough to omit showing `Exit` at the next module interface if you want to hide it from most of the rest of the program.

Comment: Note that if you expect to never have to debug this exception, perhaps due to using it for control flow, you should probably use `raise_notrace` instead of `raise`: http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#VALraise_notrace

Comment: @antron I agree with you in the sense that the intention seems to be to use the exception very locally, and also that it is part of the normal control flow of the program and should be inexpensive to raise. And at the same time, the OP is not saying that they do not expect to have to debug the exception. They are saying that they don't want the exception to have a name outside of `myfunc` (or the containing module if they follow my recommendation), which, if anything, makes it easier, not harder, to see it rise to the toplevel without being caught :)

Comment: Fair enough – I only meant a conditional recommendation for the OP, as it is in my comment. I didn't mean to suggest that you edit your answer, except maybe to incorporate the comment as a final additional note, at best. So I think the comment is sufficient :)