# how to define mutually-recursive class and exception in ocaml

Tags: class, exception, recursion, ocaml

I want to define a class foo, and an exception X, the constructor of which  takes a pair of foo's as arguments. Methods of class foo should be able to raise exception X... I can't manage to get the syntax right for these. Can anyone please suggest how to do it?

Comment: Is it okay for the exception to be local to a function? If so, there is a [recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312718/is-it-possible-to-define-an-exception-inside-a-function). Otherwise, have you tried looking at [recursive modules](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec220)?

Comment: If your class type is fairly clean and stable, you can declare it as a type before defining the exception. OCaml class typing is structural, so you don't need to define the actual class before the exception, just its type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brainstorming suggestion. Since OCaml uses structural typing for classes, you can declare the class as a type before defining the exception. Here's a sketch that works for me:

```
class type c = object method m : unit end

exception E of c * c

class myclass =
    object (self)
    method m : unit = raise (E ((self :> c), (self :> c)))
    end
```

Granted this is a bit cumbersome.